# How to select which test to run with GLib testing suite?

Tags: c, unit-testing, testing, glib

I have made several tests with GLib testing framework. I launch them by running "make check" in my test directory. How can I do to run only one test, for example, foobar ?
Is there a command such as 'make check-foobar' ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so you used gtester right, didn't do a `man gtester`?

You can use `gtester -p=/path/a/single/test/is/registered/to test-binary.bin`

---

If you can call it via `make check /some/path` depends on your buildsystem (Makefile, autotools, waf, scons, CMake,.. and the associated config files, which you did not provide)

Comment: Actually I forgot I was using gtester, with autotools masking it.

Comment: You can also call the `test-binary.bin` directly if you don't want gtester's features (e.g. stopping on the first failure): `./test-binary.bin -p /some/path`